# Error using Field Declarations with create-react-app

Tags: create-react-app

I'm using `create-react-app` with the new [Field Declaration](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields#field-declarations) which `create-react-app` supports. Unfortunately, here it is used in my code:

```
// ./src/App.js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ListContacts from './ListContacts';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    contacts: [
      {
        id: 'bob',
        name: 'bob bob',
        email: 'bob@bob.com',
        avatarURL: 'http://localhost:5001/bob.jpg'
      },
      {
        id: 'michael',
        name: 'Michael',
        email: 'michael@michael.com',
        avatarURL: 'http://localhost:5001/michael.jpg'
      },
      {
        id: 'ash',
        name: 'Ash',
        email: 'ash@ash.com',
        avatarURL: 'http://localhost:5001/ash.jpg'
      }
    ]
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ListContacts contacts={this.state.contacts} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Unfortunately, I get the error:

> Failed to compile.
>
> ./src/App.js   Line 5:  'state' is not defined  no-undef
>
> Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

Why can't I use the Field Declaration Syntax? I've had others run the project and code and it works fine on their system.

Comment: Which version of eslint are you using in your project?

Comment: I just updated to v4.13.1 (I just updated it this morning). I restarted my shell and am getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to the eslint version you are using. In which case, you can solve the issue by wrapping your code with:

```
/*eslint-disable no-undef*/
...
/*eslint-enable no-undef*/
```

Or by trying a different eslint version that does not have that issue.